# RxJs Observables problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

So basically I have an Ionic mobile application. data are retrieved from firebase database using RxJS Observables. I wanted to put a search feature in one of my modules but im having a hard time because of observables retrieving data in real time, my initial logic is to push the retrieved data in an array and that array will be the basis for the search feature. Is there any other way?

```
initializeItems() {
    this.travelList$ = this.plsdala.getTravelList()
        .snapshotChanges()
        .map(
            changes => {
                return changes.map(c => ({
                    key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
                })).slice().reverse();//to reverse order
            })
    this.travelList$.subscribe(res => {
        res.map(c => {
            ListOfitems.push(c.toAddress);
        })
    })
}
```

`ListOfitems.push(c.toAddress)`, I cannot check if this is pushed in the array since i cant print it. Have been debugging for hours but I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: how do i print the listOfitems in console? i cannot print it in console :(( someone help me been debugging for days already :((

Comment: why cant you print? use console.log..

Comment: Maybe you can't print ListOfItems because the loop never executes?

Comment: If you add 'debugger;' to a separate line inside your 'res.map' block, you can easily see if the ListOfItems ever gets populated.

Comment: Hi sir ringo.the method is initialized in the constructor.

Comment: how do i structure that sir riingo? the debugger inside the res.map block

Comment: The code looks wrong to me. You put a .map() inside the return function for a .map(). We would need to see more of the code and the data that youre working with to have a better idea. Can you put all this on a jsbin or repl or something

Comment: If you put a console.log(c.toAddress) on a new line above the ListOfItems.push() line, you will see if it's ever running. Also, when you chain all the method calls together like this, it's very hard to debug. Are you sure snapshotChanges() is working right?

Comment: hi this is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/y3opKdOAiky2YCf00beR?p=preview

Comment: yes sir ringo. snapshotChanges() is working right since everytime there are changes it updates or it gives data in real time

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty sure I'm not the right person to help you, but the .map() inside the .map() (lines 51-53) looks wrong. You really need to understand .map() first.

Comment: sir ringo please help me :((